# OSX Yosemite 10.10.3 Date added wrong?

Tags: finder, file

I download some files. Using Path Finder, it says `Today` under the **Date Added** column. `4/5/14` under **Date Modified**.

I then copy the file off to a external hard disk, but there it shows `4/5/14` under the **Date Added** and **Date Modified** column.

What is wrong? Shouldn't the `Date Added` remain as `Today`?

In Finder, the Downloads folder is the same as Path Finder, but for the external hard disk, the **Date Added** column is `--`.

Comment: What format is the external hard drive?

Comment: @Mark its ExFAT.